# Ethereum balance is 0 on local (geth) despite etherchain.org reporting it has ether

Tags: synchronization, balances

I bought some Ether over 4 hours ago:  https://etherchain.org/account/0x3d74c07013285b31049ecc7d9cb078cd1aa8ea96

When I run [the following script](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts#checking-account-balances) on my local machine I get:

```
$ geth console
> function checkAllBalances() {
    var totalBal = 0;
    for (var acctNum in eth.accounts) {
        var acct = eth.accounts[acctNum];
        var acctBal = web3.fromWei(eth.getBalance(acct), "ether");
        totalBal += parseFloat(acctBal);
        console.log("  eth.accounts[" + acctNum + "]: \t" + acct + " \tbalance: " + acctBal + " ether");
    }
    console.log("  Total balance: " + totalBal + " ether");
};
> checkAllBalances()
  eth.accounts[0]:    0x3d74c07013285b31049ecc7d9cb078cd1aa8ea96    balance: 0 ether

$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.5.9-stable
Git Commit: a07539fb88db7231d18db918ed7a6a4e32f97450
Protocol Versions: [63 62]
Network Id: 1
Go Version: go1.8
OS: darwin
GOPATH=
GOROOT=/usr/local/Cellar/go/1.8/libexec
```

Comment: @5chdn `eth.syncing` => `false`  and now it's returning:  `{
  currentBlock: 168215,
  highestBlock: 3429572,
  knownStates: 0,
  pulledStates: 0,
  startingBlock: 167751
}`

Comment: Well, wait till you are synchronized then.

Comment: @5chdn makes sense.   Thanks.  Could you post as an answer and I'll accept.  Cheers.  (If you know a link to a good intro tutorial with that described I'd be very grateful)